# Inside 1D interval optimization

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry

I was wandering if I can optimize this function such that after optimization it will use the minimum computation effort.

```
public class Rectangle2 {
    Vector2 origin;
    Vector2 size;
    public boolean isInside(double x, double y){
        return false;
    }
}
```

The origin is considered the minimum of x and y

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the minimum of x and y

Comment: This micro-optimization will be of very little benefit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking us to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
x-= origin.x;
y-= origin.y;
return x > 0 && x < size.x && y > 0 && y < size.y;
```

or

```
x-= origin.x;
y-= origin.y;
return x * (size.x - x) * y * (size.y - y) > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
public class Test
{

private static Double MIN_X=0.0;
private static Double MIN_Y=0.0;

private static Double LENGTH=5.0;
private static Double BREADTH=3.0;

private static Integer X_INDEX=0;
private static Integer Y_INDEX=1;

private static Integer LENGTH_INDEX=0;
private static Integer BREADTH_INDEX=1;

Vector<Double> origin=new Vector<>();
Vector<Double> size=new Vector<>();


public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Test test=new Test();

    test.origin.add(X_INDEX, MIN_X);
    test.origin.add(Y_INDEX, MIN_Y);


    test.size.add(LENGTH_INDEX,LENGTH);
    test.size.add(BREADTH_INDEX,BREADTH);

    System.out.println(test.isInside(2.0, 3.0));


}

public boolean isInside(double x, double y)
{
    boolean result=false;

    if((origin.get(X_INDEX)+size.get(LENGTH_INDEX)> x)  &&  (origin.get(Y_INDEX)+size.get(BREADTH_INDEX) > y))
    {
        result=true;

    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: The implementation is incorrect, the output is not consistent.

Comment: can you provide some test cases where it fails.